# How to implement check for program files folder in a windows installer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, file, installation

I have a VSTO setup project as per [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/ff937654.aspx).
This site mentions that I do not need to implement security if I install the program in the Program files folder; but it does not explain how to implement this in a setup project (as custom actions, etc.)

Notes:

- Need to be able to detect C:\Program Files\ under 32-bit systems or C:\Program FIles (x86)\ under x64 systems.
- I am using VS2010 setup project.

Answer (score 1):

A Visual Studio setup project already uses ProgramFilesFolder property for Application Folder. This property is resolved to "C:\Program Files" on 32-bit machines and to "C:\Program FIles (x86)" on 64-bit machines.

Comment: My question is how to detect Program files programatically to avoid the user installing it in the wrong path

Comment: ProgramFilesFolder property is set automatically by Windows Installer, so you can get the path from this value. You can also use the Windows API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This method gets the required path in C# (For custom actions):

```
    public static string GetProgramFilesPath()
    {
        Environment.SpecialFolder folder = Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem? Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles: Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86;
        return Environment.GetFolderPath(folder);
    }
```

Note: [Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem.aspx) is supported for .NET4.0 onwards. It uses any CPU option.